# Redirect direct link to image to php page with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a page that list many photo links. Click on a link will take you to a page.php page to see the image itself with watermark and some other stuff (added by php). What I want is that if people go directly to the big image (no watermark by itself), they'll be redirected to the page.php page so that the watermark is applied.

Example of link on a regular html file

```
<a href="/page.php?i=image1" target="new">Link to Image 1</a>
```

Part of page.php

```
<?php $file = $_GET['i']; ?>
<img src="/img/<?php echo $file ?>.png" />
```

I put in the .htaccess this line of code below that I found in this forum. However, while the redirect works, the image doesn't display on the page.php and on the other html files. I guess the image links were affected by the redirect, too and become broken. Could you help? Thanks!

```
RewriteRule ^img/(.*)\.png$ /page.php?i=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: But the redirect works? eg: site.com/img/someimg.png redirect to site.com/i=someimg.png? PD. StackOverflow is not a forum

Comment: Yes, the redirect worked - like you described - just that the image is not in there. View source verifies the image link is correct. That made me think the image link is affected by the redirect.

Comment: the image src path is correct?? I mean, the route generated is correct? The redirect is not the problem

Comment: Yes. The generated path is correct: src="/img/image1.png"

Comment: Ok, I posted the solution as anwer, don't forget check it! ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your img tag is liking to the rewrite URL. So, you should allow empty referrals, that's what the first line do:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^$
RewriteRule ^img/(.*)\.png$ /page.php?i=$1 [NC,L]
```